# mongodb How get the list by using Criteria Object

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongorepository

Below is my sample json object i have different Ids i want get particular id of countries. user will pass the id and countries Key as request other then countries  i have other list as well user will pass as attribute (which list user excepting)

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria().andOperator(
Criteria.where("Id").is(Id).and(attribute).is(attribute));
Query searchUserQuery = new Query(criteria);

// to print the mongodb query for debug purposes
System.out.println(criteria.getCriteriaObject());
Query searchUserQuery = new Query(criteria);
Info result =mongoTemplate .findOne(searchUserQuery, Info.class,COLLECTION);
```

Json format which is from  database

```
{
  "Id": "691021",
  "Type": "PR",
  "countries": [{
    "country": "AUS",
    "isoCode": "124",
    "startDate": "2015-08-17T12:30:44.789-4:00",
    "endDate": "2015-08-17T12:30:44.789-4:00"
  }, {
    "country": "US",
    "isoCode": "456",
    "startDate": "2015-11-11T12:30:44.789-4:00",
    "endDate": "2017-08-17T12:30:44.789-4:00"
  }]
}
```

I tried with like my mongodb Query generated like { "$and" : [ { "Id" : "691021"} , { "countries" : { "$regex" : "countries"}}]}

i am excepting output like below

```
"countries": [{
  "country": "AUS",
  "isoCode": "124",
  "startDate": "2015-08-17T12:30:44.789-4:00",
  "endDate": "2015-08-17T12:30:44.789-4:00"
}, {
  "country": "US",
  "isoCode": "456",
  "startDate": "2015-11-11T12:30:44.789-4:00",
  "endDate": "2017-08-17T12:30:44.789-4:00"
}]
```

Comment: you may want to add a tag `java` so that more java experts can see the question.

Comment: I have tired with like operator with regex  mongodb Query generated like { "$and" : [ { "offeringId" : "PMRS691021"} , { "countries" : { "$regex" : "countries"}}]}

Comment: do you have an actually working "native" mongodb query that does the expected. From what I could take out of the description this might require usage of the aggregation framework.

Comment: I don't know Java, but if we are talking about shell query, it would be something like: `db.collName.find({Id: "691021", "countries.country": /code/});`

Comment: Thanks for reply i want to get all countries for the Id "691021" what i need pass for example employee i have multiple address  based one employee Id i want get all address of employee(one to many) Can you tell me the shell query base don that i can change my java code